# [Python + Bokeh 0.12.5]: How to make density plots?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying out Bokeh but cannot find any reference to Density Plots.

This example (using ggplot) was for Bokeh 0.11 and has been removed from the gallery on the last Bokeh version: 
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.11.0/docs/gallery/density.html

On Bokeh 0.12.5 it doesn't work because ggplot 0.11 doesn't have any draw() method.

Has it been implemented natively or is there a workaround?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ggplot import aes, diamonds, geom_density, ggplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

As @bigreddot states we can remove this line:
<strike>from bokeh import mpl</strike>

```
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, show

g = ggplot(diamonds, aes(x='price', color='cut')) + geom_density()
g.show()

plt.title("Density ggplot-based plot in Bokeh.")

output_file("density.html", title="density.py example")

show(mpl.to_bokeh())
```

[image]

Comment: As of Bokeh `012.5`, MPL compat has been deprecated, and will be removed completely in a future `1.0` release.

Comment: @bigreddot Thanks.

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you very much, but it is not yet complete. 
The graph is an independent frame. Only after closing it the web page is created. It reads axes and title but the graph is not there... 
Do you have an idea why?